# Foreign language turns gibberish in DT::datatable when runtime: shiny is activated

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, dt

The following table in rmd file turns out fine when runtime: shiny is omitted.

````
---
title: "Test"
runtime: shiny
output: 
    html_document:
        toc: true
---

```{r}
require(DT)
datatable(data.frame(test=c("テスト")))
```
````

Comment: This works for me.  What platform are you using, would it be Windows ? I am using the following `R version 3.2.3` on `Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)` and shiny `shiny_0.12.2`. Perhaps the following link will help https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/136

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the link. I am using `R version 3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336)` on `Running under: Windows >= 8 x64` with `shiny_0.13.1 `.

Comment: Seems to be Windows specific. Same issue here.